# How to apply pan & Zoom separately for 4 picturebox in the same form

Tags: c#, image, zooming, picturebox, pan

In my project I am using 4 pictureBoxs in a single form.

While applying the pan and zoom function separately, the first image works correctly but, if I go for the second one the first image bitmap changes to exceptions.

I don't know why it changes like this. Please help me.

I am using **C Sharp.**

Comment: The people who can help you (not me, I am a Mathematica user) will want to know what language you are using at a minimum, and they will probably need to see your code as well.

Comment: Im sorry but it is almost impossible to attempt to help you solve this issue without some code for us to look at

Comment: @Murugesan Great that you solved the problem, feel free to post the solution as an answer to your own question so that other people can make use of it if the run in to the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution for my question.

My problem is Bitmap changing into exceptions, because am used same location in cache. So data was corrupted. To overcome this we have to assign the new location for Bitmap.

```
Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap("D:\a.jpg");
```

Likewise i assigned 4 variables and used to display the images.

Comment: Don't forget to except you own answer.